# Android Google Maps - как удалить маршрут?

Tags: android, route, polyline

Есть 20 маршрутов, построенные с помощью координат и Polyline. Нужно по клику показывать выбранные маршруты - с этим проблем нет. НО как удалить маршрут если выбор отменили??? Не всю карту очистить, а именно один маршрут (что б  другие выбранные маршруты не исчезли)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно хранить где-то массив объектов Polyline и потом вызывать метод remove() у объекта который нужно убрать с карты.

Описание метода: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139271/google-maps-android-api-v2-how-to-remove-polylines-from-the-map